# add to data to 2 different listBoxes on 2 different forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, listbox

trip form, delivery form, pickup form

on the main form i have a button that takes you to the trips from where you enter some data into text boxed then when you press add it will either add a pickup or a delivery depending how what data you entered to a `listbox` on the main form

how would i get it so that if i add a delivery to the `listbox` in the main form it also adds the delivery to a `listbox` in the delivery form

or if i add a pickup to the `listbox` on the main forms it also adds a pickup to the `listbox` on the pickup form

some example code how i add a delivery:

**MAIN FORM ADD DELIVERY BUTTON:**

```
    private void btnDelivery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        deliveryForm.deliverytrips = new DeliveryTrips();
        //New delivery- note added to the deliveryForm object


        deliveryForm.ShowDialog();
        //Show the deliveryForm. ShowDialog ensures that the form has the exclusive focus until it is closed.

        if (deliveryForm.deliverytrips != null)
        //if null then the "cancel" button was pressed
        {
            DeliveryTrips newApp = deliveryForm.deliverytrips;
            //Get the delivery object from the form

            theDelivery.addDeliveryTrip(newApp);
            //Add the delivery to the summary
        }
        updateList();
        //Update the list object to reflect the delivery in the summary
```

**CODE FOR TRIP FROM TO ADD DELIVERY TO LISTBOX ON MAIN FORM:**

```
    public partial class frmDelivery : Form
    {
    private DeliveryTrips theDeliveryTrips;
    //The DeliveryTrips object being created/edited


    public DeliveryTrips deliverytrips
    {   //Property to allow access to theDeliveryTrips
        get { return theDeliveryTrips; }
        set { theDeliveryTrips = value; }
    }

    public frmDelivery()
    {   //Constructor
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void frmDelivery_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //When makeing the form visible, set the text boxes to reflect the values in
        //theDeliveryTrips.

        if (theDeliveryTrips != null)
        {

            txtDescription.Text = "Delivery";
            txtDescription.ReadOnly = true;
            txtCustomerName.Text = theDeliveryTrips.customername;
            txtCustomerAddress.Text = theDeliveryTrips.customeraddress;
            txtTime.Text = theDeliveryTrips.arrivaltime.ToString();


        }

    }


    private void btnAdd_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        theDeliveryTrips.description = txtDescription.Text;
        theDeliveryTrips.customername = txtCustomerName.Text;
        theDeliveryTrips.customeraddress = txtCustomerAddress.Text;
        theDeliveryTrips.arrivaltime = TimeSpan.Parse(txtTime.Text);

        this.Hide();
        //Hide the forum
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        theDeliveryTrips = null;
        //Set theDeliveryTrips to null as to remove any changes made

        this.Hide();
        //Hide the forum
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting them all to use the same DataContext?

Comment: how would i do that im new to C# so not long started learning how to code in C#

Comment: consider using reactive extensions.  it also has a scheduler that respects the UI context

Answer (score 0):

You could create a public method in your frmDelivery class:

```
public void ListBoxAdd(string item)
{
     listbox_frmDelivery.Items.Add(item); // or whatever your list box is called
}
```

then in your main where you initialized frmDelivery you can call:

```
deliveryForm.ListBoxAdd("Added From Main Form by pub method");
```

**or** you can search for it on your main form:

```
        int indexOfListBox = deliveryForm.Controls.IndexOfKey("frmDelivery listbox id");
        if (indexOfListBox != -1)// if not -1 we found it
        {
            ListBox deliveryListBox = (ListBox)deliveryForm.Controls[indexOfListBox];
            deliveryListBox.Items.Add("Added from Main form by searching index");
        }
```

Comment: wont that all the items on the main `listbox` to the `listbox` in the delivery form?

Comment: "how would i get it so that if i add a delivery to the listbox in the main form it also adds the delivery to a listbox in the delivery form" Sure will.  Isn't that your requirement? If not maybe I misunderstood!